# Solr doesn't start and log file is getting deleted

Tags: solr

solr-5.2.1 version

My Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

I used [this url](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-solr-5-2-1-on-ubuntu-14-04) to install solr, did all steps but after

```
sudo service solr start
```

Waiting up to 30 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983
Still not seeing Solr listening on 8983 after 30 seconds!

finally am getting this error:

```
tail: cannot open ‘/var/solr/logs/solr.log’ for reading: No such file or directory
```

I created the touch solr.log file. but will start the solr log file is removed.

How to fix this error?

Comment: just had the same problem, and it appears to be because of a JVM option... you can check solr-xxxx-console.log to see if jvm is not starting up due to an option problem

Answer (score 2):

Just update java version to [java 8](http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/)

Run command:

```
sudo bin/solr start
```

For example:

```
Vostro-3550:/opt/solr-6.0.0$ sudo bin/solr start
```

Then open browser and the past:
http://localhost:8983/solr/

Comment: I fixed this issue . my server don't have memory so solr is not worked . after update the memory its worked perfectly .

Comment: D'oh! I just realized I was still running Java 7 on the server that was running into this same error. I re-provisioned the server (CentOS 7) using the `java-1.8.0-openjdk` package and now everything's working.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced exactly same problem :

```
  cannot open ‘/var/solr/logs/solr.log’ for reading: No such file or directory

  Found 1 Solr nodes: 

  Solr process pid from /var/solr/solr-8983.pid not found.
  Service solr installed.
```

in my case its because of low memory available. I found the prove in `kern.log`
`Out of memory: Kill process pid () score 227 or sacrifice child` . 
and it worked when I increased the  RAM size.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of solr you are using?
I am using solr5.4 and it's working all fine

```
root@ashu-700-430qe:/opt/solr-5.4.0# bin/solr start
Waiting up to 30 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983 [/]  
Started Solr server on port 8983 (pid=5509). Happy searching!

root@ashu-700-430qe:/opt/solr-5.4.0#
```

I am also using Oracle Java 8

[image]

And my logs are also working fine. Here is the listing with permissions:

```
root@ashu-700-430qe:/opt/solr-5.4.0/server/logs# ls -lrt
total 176
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 41795 Jan 10 08:02 solr_log_20160216_2032
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 49305 Jan 10 08:02 solr_gc_log_20160216_2032
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 26960 Feb 16 20:33 solr_gc.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 25547 Feb 16 20:33 solr.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 22764 Feb 16 20:33 solr-8983-console.log
root@ashu-700-430qe:/opt/solr-5.4.0/server/logs#
```

P.S. I install good amount of tools as root as I do a lot of evaluations. I just downloaded the solr5.4 zip file and unzipped into /opt - very much OOTB installation with no setup or configuration. You can install Apache SOLR from [here](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/lucene/solr/5.4.1)

Comment: my server is digital ocean
1. wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/5.4.0/solr-5.4.0.tgz
2. tar xzf solr-5.4.0.tgz solr-5.4.0/bin/install_solr_service.sh --strip-components=2
3. sudo bash ./install_solr_service.sh solr-5.4.0.tgz
 sudo bash ./install_solr_service.sh solr-5.4.0.tgz
Extracting solr-5.4.0.tgz to /opt
Installing symlink /opt/solr -> /opt/solr-5.4.0 ...
Installing /etc/init.d/solr script ...
Moving existing /var/solr/solr.in.sh to /etc/default/solr.in.sh ...
/var/solr/data/solr.xml already exists. Skipping install ...

Comment: Found 1 Solr nodes: 

Solr process 990 from /var/solr/solr-8983.pid not found.
Service solr installed.
root@dindudu:/opt# sudo service solr status

Found 1 Solr nodes: 

Solr process 990 from /var/solr/solr-8983.pid not found.

Comment: @DineshKumar. What does that mean? Sorry i couldn't get it. I am starting solr as a root and all my solr directories are owned by root. This is OOTB solr installation..it works for me in linux as well as in Mac and Windows.

Comment: Y am getting this error
 sudo service solr status

Found 1 Solr nodes: 

Solr process 990 from /var/solr/solr-8983.pid not found.

Comment: Your Flow am getting this error 

bin/solr start
Waiting up to 30 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983Still not seeing Solr listening on 8983 after 30 seconds!
tail:  [-]  cannot open ‘/opt/solr-5.4.0/server/logs/solr.log’ for reading: No such file or directory

Comment: MY LOG root@dindudu:/opt/solr-5.4.0# cd server/logs/
root@dindudu:/opt/solr-5.4.0/server/logs# ls
solr-8983-console.log  solr_gc.log